# Can a case statement have if then else and an or clause

Tags: sql

Good Day To All I'm a newbie to SQL and want to perform the following in SQL. I've done it in Crystal but do not know if can be done in SQl. Here is how I done it in Crystal can this be done in SQL:

`{@Adjust Code}` and `{@Adjust Code WH}` are 2 variables that were checked for null values if null put the work 'Blank' in the field

Can the below code be put in the select statement :

```
if {RV_CLAIM_DETAILS.NET} <> 0
    then {RV_CLAIM_DETAILS.NET}

    else if ({@Adjust Code} in ["#C", "A2", "24"] or
            {@Adjust Code} = "23" and {@Adjust Code WH} = "24")
             then {RV_CLAIM_DETAILS.CONTRVAL}
```

Regards,
DAvid

Comment: In which select satement? Of which implementation? Have you tried something and failed/stuck?

Comment: A case statement performs if/else logic.  Since you knew enough to include that in the subject line, why not simply try it?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 2):

The standard SQL way of representing this logic is to use a `case` statement:

```
(case when RV_CLAIM_DETAILS.NET <> 0
      then RV_CLAIM_DETAILS.NET
      when "@Adjust Code" in ('#C', 'A2', '24') or
           "@Adjust Code" = '23' and "@Adjust Code WH" = '24'
      then RV_CLAIM_DETAILS.CONTRVAL
 end) as myValue
```

This has exactly the same semantics as your statement.  If the first clause matches, then that value is returned.  If none match, then `NULL` is returned.

Some notes.  First, SQL uses single quotes, not double quotes, to delimit strings.  That said, some database engines support double quotes for that purpose.

Second, in general column names starting with `'@'` are not allowed, unless they are escaped.  One way to escape names is using double quotes.  That said, some database engines use square braces or back quotes for the same purpose.  I also removed the curly braces, which are not needed for SQL.

Comment: Thank you Gordon it worked perfectly. I was not sure if this could be done in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Simple CASE expression:

```
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END 
Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Example:

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =
      CASE ProductLine
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'
         ELSE 'Not for sale'
      END,
   Name
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber;
GO
```